# Copy a range and paste only rows with values into another sheet at the next blank row?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to build off of what was solved here:

[How do you copy a range and paste only rows with values into another sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547313/how-do-you-copy-a-range-and-paste-only-rows-with-values-into-another-sheet)

I want to do this with a bigger range (O1:X500 on the sheet named "RGDR") copying only the rows with values in them and then paste them in the new sheet ("ACTUALFUNC") in the next blank row.

The sheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vvXQxBGffwBAjbXKqx4N-ZFcX40wuV7gg9flb6STWtA/edit?usp=sharing

Below is the code I already tried. It only brings over the first column of data.

```
function copyRangeNoEmpties(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('RGDR');
  var copyToSheet=ss.getSheetByName('ACTUALFUNC');
  var copyFromRange=sh.getRange('O1:X500');
  var vA=copyFromRange.getValues();
  var oA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    if(vA[i][0])
    {
      oA.push([vA[i][0]]);
    }
  }
  var copyToRange=copyToSheet.getRange(1,1,oA.length,1);
  copyToRange.setValues(oA);
}
```

Looking to build a ongoing list of results by running this once daily. Any help or input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your only putting the first column of data into `oA` .  Instead try `oA.push(vA[i])`

Comment: Also change `var copyToRange=copyToSheet.getRange(1,1,oA.length,1);` to `var copyToRange=copyToSheet.getRange(1,1,oA.length,copyFromRange.getWidth());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will append your data to the next row on your destination sheet.

```
function copyRangeNoEmpties(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('RGDR');
  var des=ss.getSheetByName('ACTUALFUNC');
  var src=sh.getRange('O1:X500');
  var vA=src.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i].join("")) {
      des.appendRow(vA[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great! Cooper you are awesome! Many thanks!